# Can't Upload Large Audio Files PHP music site

Tags: php

So yes I did look at articles and other forums here and I seen those forums that say
set your

php.ini

post_max_size =10M

upload_max_filesize = 10M

max_execution_time = 300

max_input_time = 300

But LOOK im NOT uploading IMAGES, IM uploading 1mb to 1GB audio files, and also
I have another ini files that are for users, its called users.ini.
The developer that helped me is so busy so he cant fix it at the moment, But I do know where to find the files, also Im using Vesta for my FTP.

This was working a few hours ago when uploading but them it stopped working WHY

**If anyone wants to check out my site and upload a large audio file be my guess!**

subplays.net

Comment: A limit of 10MB will not suffice for a 1GB upload, regardless of file type.

Comment: I never said I used that, Im using that for a example I found from a fourm. I use 2024MB for both of them

Comment: Did you checked your log files for errors? Memory exhausted?

Comment: @EliasSoares OMG, your proabably right, because guess what! Uploads were all fine, I did hourly uploads all day today they were all big files and they uploaded  then I stopped at 9:47 and guess what ithe issue came back, It could be memory, BUT how do I check memory on my server, do I need "Putty" or some sort  terminal network

Comment: Errors log should show you.